# Neo4j - Dijkstra Algorithm with weights shown in path results

Tags: java, neo4j

So far I am getting all paths from Dijkstra's Algorithm as shown below:

```
        for(Node node_a: GlobalGraphOperations.at(graphDB).getAllNodes()){
            for(Node node_b: GlobalGraphOperations.at(graphDB).getAllNodes()){
                if(node_a.getId() != node_b.getId()){
                    Iterator<WeightedPath> paths = dijkstra.findAllPaths(node_a, node_b ).iterator();

                    while (paths.hasNext()){
                        WeightedPath path = paths.next();
                        Iterable<Relationship> relationships = path.relationships();
                        String pathString = "";
                        for(Node node :path.nodes()){
                            pathString +=  node.getProperty("company_name") + " ->";

                        }

                        System.out.println(pathString);
                        System.out.println(path);
                    }
                }

            }

        }
```

However I want to get the independent lengths of each relationship. For example, I have a path as follows:

```
(3)--[PROGRESSED_TO,3800]-->(7)--[PROGRESSED_TO,4350]-->(894) weight:0.088345867
3Com ->Nortel ->Bay Networks
```

But I want to also, be able to see  `3Com -(length:24)->Nortel -(length:10)->Bay Networks`

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: The word is 'Algorithm'. It's a proper name. No abbreviation.

Comment: @EJP I'd appreciate if you didn't troll on here. There's no need to be snarky or rude.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also iterate over the path's relationships:

```
for(Relationship rel :path.relationships()){
  pathString +=  "(length:" + rel.getProperty("length") + ")";
}
```

or over all elements

```
for(PropertyContainer pc :path){
  ... pc.getProperty("foobar")...
}
```